# Создание MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Попробовал сделать соединение через `php`, ошибок не вылезло, но и базы и таблицы не появилось. [Вот код](http://ideone.com/y3WzJW):

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'sew810i9', '1234') or die ('Нет соединения');
$base = "CREATE DATABASE mydb" or die ("База не создана");
$table = "CREATE TABLE mytable (title TEXT)";
mysql_select_db($table, $db);
```

Сообщения компилятора:

```
prog.cpp:1:8: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
prog.cpp:3:21: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
prog.cpp:3:34: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
prog.cpp:3:46: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
prog.cpp:3:62: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
prog.cpp:1:7: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
prog.cpp:2:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
prog.cpp:3:1: error: ‘$db’ does not name a type
prog.cpp:4:1: error: ‘$base’ does not name a type
prog.cpp:5:1: error: ‘$table’ does not name a type
prog.cpp:6:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

Comment: @sew810i9 хватит форум мучать, по моему для этого есть статьи в инете и учебники в которых подробно рассказывается как это делается.

Comment: Вы языки немного попутали. Код на php, а транслировать пытаетесь транслятором C++, (g++ v4.7.2). Лихо

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, используйте PDO (*где б табличку вывесить, чтоб не повторять по сто раз?*)

Во-вторых, соблюдайте порядок выполнения **запросов** (*которых у вас я не наблюдаю*)

```
// Для начала - подключились
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
// Теперь создаете базу
mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci",$db);
// Базу создали, но не плохо бы её выбрать
mysql_query("USE `mydb`",$db);
// А вот теперь - можно и таблицу создавать
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable`(`title` text NOT NULL)",$db);
```

Comment: спасибо большое! Еще вопрос задам, не подскажите как реализовать добавление файла на сайт,  я так понимаю часть данных типа название и описание хранятся в базе, а вот как быть с изображением для моего файла (скриншот), и самим файлом. Я принцип не могу понять как все устроено. Ведь для каждого нового файла должна создаваться папка с именем каким то и для скриншота и потом еще это вывести как то надо. У самого опыта пока не хватает. Надо примерно так сделать http://upwap.ru/3136179 а у меня сейчас http://upwap.ru/3136188 вот так

Answer (score 0):

Базу выбирайте функцией `mysql_select_db`, а не как предложил [[@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)](/users/4058/deonis) (mysql_query("USE `mydb`",$db);)

```
mysql_select_db('mydb);
```